# Correctly setting environment

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment, gentoo, gdm, environment-variables

I'm using zsh and gdm to run gnome. Some time ago I discovered that variables are not set correctly. For example LANG/LC_ALL are incorrect (`""` instead of `en_GB.UTF-8`).

I split the `.zshrc` into `.zshrc` and `.profile`. In the latter I set the environment variables, but how can I set the variables before the session starts? I tried a few choices (`.xinitrc`, `.xsessionrc`) but none seemed to work.

**Edit** To clarify - I used `.profile` and *manually* sourced it in `.zshrc`. It does not change question anyway.

Comment: Is your `.profile` not loaded at all, or is something else overwriting the locale variables? (Try setting some other variable like `export MACIEJ_PROFILE=yes` to make sure. `set -x` in `.profile` may be a good way to check what is being executed in and after `.profile`, if it's read at all.) There is no point in sourcing `.profile` from `.zshrc`.

Comment: Is this a problem in terminal windows or elsewhere? Do you get your desired locale settings when you run `ssh localhost zsh`? What about `ssh localhost bash`? If bash is ok but not zsh, maybe you put something in `/etc/zshenv` or `~/.zshenv` (which is pretty much always a bad idea).

Comment: No the shell is working OK (before and after split). The problem is that `gnome-session` does not have this variebles set.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simple way is to invent a time machine, visit the various people who devised shell startup files and tell them to cleanly distinguish between three things:

- session setup, e.g. environment variables;
- session launching, i.e., e.g. starting a command-line shell or a window manager or running `startx`;
- shell initialization, e.g. aliases, prompt, key bindings.

It's not too hard to get session vs. shell right in a portable way: login-time initialization goes into `.profile` (or `.zprofile`, or `.login`), shell initialization goes in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`. I've previously written about [`.bash_profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980), [zsh vs. other shells](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile/187673#187673), [more about portability (mostly about bash)](https://superuser.com/questions/217431/bash-shell-how-to-reconcile-portable-configuration-files-and-gui-terminal-start/217816#217816), [more about who reads `.profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash/183956#183956).

A remaining problem is distinguishing between session setup and session launching. In most cases, `~/.profile` is executed when you log in and can double as both, but there are exceptions:

- If your login shell is (t)csh or zsh, `~/.login` and `~/.zprofile` is sourced instead of `~/.profile`. Ditto for bash and `~/.bash_profile`, but this is easily solved by sourcing `~/.profile` from `~/.bash_profile`.
- If you log in under a [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29) (xdm, gdm, kdm, …), whether your `~/.profile` is read depends on the version of the program, on your distribution (Linux or otherwise), and on what session type you choose.

  - If you count on the display manager to start a session for you, your `.profile` must set environment variables but not start a session (e.g. a window manager).
  - The traditional configuration file for X sessions is `~/.xsession`, doing both session setup and session launching. So the file can be essentially `. ~/.xsession; . ~/.xinitrc`. Some distributions source `~/.profile` before `~/.xsession`. Modern distributions only source `~/.xsession` when you select a “custom” session from the display manager, and such a session is not always available.
  - Your session manager may have its own way of setting environment variables. (That's an optional part of your desktop environment, chosen by you through a configuration file or by selecting a session type when logging in; don't confuse it with the session startup scripts provided by the display manager, which are executed under your user but chosen on a system-wide basis. Yes, it's a mess.)

In summary, `~/.profile` is the right place for environment variables. If it's not read, try sourcing it from `~/.xsession` (and start your X programs from there), or look for a system-specific method (which may depend on your distribution, display manager if any, session type if display manager, and desktop environment or session manager).

Comment: `.xsession` was the file I was looking for.

Comment: I agree strongly with everything except your summary.  I don't think you established this point.  If your `.profile` sources `.bashrc` or similar, then you can reliably set environment variables in `.bashrc` for not only login sessions, but for new shells that need different settings, e.g. if you start an `xterm` from `gnome-terminal` and want different `dircolors`.

Comment: @Mikel If you set environment variables in `.bashrc`, they will override your previous settings. For example, if you've started a Screen or Tmux instance with particular environment variables, anything you set in `.bashrc` will override these settings. `LS_COLORS` is a special case because it's really a per-terminal setting; ideally it should be set by the terminal emulator, and setting it in a shell rc file is a best-effort workaround.

Answer (score 1):

In Gentoo documentation there is article [Gentoo Linux Localization Guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/guide-localization.xml). [Chapter 3](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/guide-localization.xml#doc_chap3) is about setting locale.

> Most typically users only set the LANG variable on the global basis. This example is for a unicode German locale:
>
> Code Listing 3.1: Setting the default system locale in `/etc/env.d/02locale`
>
> ```
> LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
> ```

In my Gentoo `LANG` is set in this file and everything is working properly...

```
pbm@tauri ~ $ cat /etc/env.d/02locale 
LANG="pl_PL.UTF-8"

pbm@tauri ~ $ locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Beware that the part you quoted is ok, but the guide also recommends setting an environment variable in `.bashrc`, which is wrong (see my answer and in particular http://superuser.com/questions/217431).

Comment: Thanks for so detailed info... :) I've never used that .bashrc part - settings in `env.d` are more universal.

Comment: Also it is per system instead of per-user. I prefer to keep system settings separate from user settings.