# Get/Set environment variables in a different tty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, aix

I'm using a tool (Autokey) that spawns in a new shell.  Cool tool, but I want to pull info from my current shell.

Say I'm on pts/0 and I have a variable set: VAR1=yes.  In another shell, I want to be able to read the variable from pts/0 and take action accordingly.  Would also be nice to be able to set the variable.  Any way to do either?

MORE INFO THAT YOU DON'T NEED TO READ (probably):
What I'm doing is creating a reliable way to set up my environment on ANY remote *nix box (AIX, RHEL, SuSE).  With one key combo, I run bash, set -o settings, set EDITOR and VISUAL, etc.

NFS is not reliably available.  I could change my profile but I can't change root's or I screw it up for the other admins.  Essentially, I'm left with whatever I can do over ssh.  And it works the way I have it - it's just not pretty.  I'd prefer something interactive.

For my specific situation, I've considered saving the variable to a file.  That works, as long as I'm local.  If I ssh out, saving a file remotely doesn't work.

The tool uses Python so maybe there's a way in Python to read a variable from another shell.  I doubt that Python would be able to if Bash can't.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8344/117549 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27555/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91282/117549

Comment: One approach is to set up your own profile the way you like it, then when you become root, you can `source ~yourself/.bashrc`

Comment: Good point - and with autokey I can source it with a single key combo.  That's probably what I'll do.  Still, I wonder if there is a way to modify environment variables in another shell.  Probably not without hacking systemd - or maybe bash.