# rxvt-unicode + mc - strange characters in root shell only

Tags: fonts, rxvt, mc

Using rxvt-unicode-9.11 and mc-4.7.5.2, and using zsh-4.3.11 as my login shell, I find that I get strange characters, eg â instead of lines being drawn.

Interestingly however, launching urxvt from any root shell, and then running mc inside of that renders the lines correctly.

In Xdefaults I am not setting a font.

I thought that any child shells should inherit the same as the parent shell, but clearly here it is not.

Exports in parent:

```
COLON_SEPARATED=MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH
COLORFGBG='7;default'
COLORTERM=rxvt
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK='/lib64/udev/rules.d /etc/dconf/db /etc/ca-certificates.conf'
CVS_RSH=ssh
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=awesome/urxvtc/2194-57-alipc-desktop-ex_TIME28147172
DISPLAY=:0.0
GDK_USE_XFT=1
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-CeLaPY/S.gpg-agent:2191:1
HOME=/home/ali
INFOPATH=/usr/share/info
JAVAC=/usr/bin/javac
JAVACMD=/usr/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jdk
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LDPATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64/nss:/usr/lib64/vdpau:/usr/lib64/qt4
LESS='-R -M --shift 5'
LOGNAME=ali
MAIL=/var/mail/ali
MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins:/opt/netscape/plugins
PAGER=/usr/bin/less
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/lib64/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/jre/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/lib64/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/jre/bin
PWD=/home/ali
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=2
SSH_AGENT_PID=2193
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-RhQcEipf2192/agent.2192
TERM=rxvt-256color
TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
USER=ali
WINDOWID=20972128
XAUTHORITY=/home/ali/.Xauthority
_=export
```

Exports in child:

```
COLON_SEPARATED=MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH
COLORFGBG='7;default'
COLORTERM=rxvt
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK='/lib64/udev/rules.d /etc/dconf/db /etc/ca-certificates.conf'
CVS_RSH=ssh
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=awesome/urxvtc/2194-57-alipc-desktop-ex_TIME28147172
DISPLAY=:0.0
GDK_USE_XFT=1
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-CeLaPY/S.gpg-agent:2191:1
HOME=/home/ali
INFOPATH=/usr/share/info
JAVAC=/usr/bin/javac
JAVACMD=/usr/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jdk
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LDPATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64/nss:/usr/lib64/vdpau:/usr/lib64/qt4
LESS='-R -M --shift 5'
LOGNAME=ali
MAIL=/var/mail/ali
MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins:/opt/netscape/plugins
OLDPWD=/home/ali
PAGER=/usr/bin/less
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/lib64/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/jre/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/lib64/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/jre/bin
PWD=/home/ali
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=4
SSH_AGENT_PID=2193
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-RhQcEipf2192/agent.2192
STY=27048.pts-2.alipc-desktop-ex
TERM=rxvt-256color
TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
USER=ali
WINDOW=0
WINDOWID=27262984
XAUTHORITY=/home/ali/.Xauthority
_=export
```

Thanks.

Edit: more information + combinations:
.zshrc:

```
# The following lines were added by compinstall

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/ali/.zshrc'

autoload -U zutil
autoload -Uz compinit
autoload -U complist
compinit
autoload -U colors
colors
# End of lines added by compinstall
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt appendhistory autocd extendedglob notify
unsetopt beep
bindkey -v
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install

#export PS1="%n#%d>"

PROMPT="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%d %{$reset_color%}%#"
RPROMPT="[%{$fg[yellow]%}%T%{$reset_color%}]"
```

locale -a:
    C
    en_GB.utf8
    en_US.utf8
    POSIX

exports from 'urxvt -e zsh -f': - A working set!

```
COLORFGBG='7;default'
COLORTERM=rxvt
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=awesome/urxvt/2199-28-alipc-desktop-ex_TIME11280170
DISPLAY=:0.0
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-d5ZFvz/S.gpg-agent:2196:1
HOME=/home/ali
LOGNAME=ali
MAIL=/var/mail/ali
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/home/ali
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=2
SSH_AGENT_PID=2198
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-sPZhKOhV2197/agent.2197
TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color
TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
USER=ali
WINDOWID=23068680
XAUTHORITY=/home/ali/.Xauthority
_=export
```

Note: I did try setting my TERM via .Xdefaults, to the one that worked in the 'clean' window:

```
urxvt*termName:  rxvt-unicode-256color
```

Though this had no effect, so it is not TERM that affects this.

Comment: In case it helps, colours in vim are _not_ correct in the root window, but as with above, render correctly in any child urxvt processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the environment variable `STY` set in the child. Given its presence and its contents, the child is actually running inside Screen. Your environment is not correct (i.e. it's lying to applications) in two ways:

- You have a Unicode terminal, and you're trying to display non-ASCII characters. Yet your environment doesn't define `LC_CTYPE`. If you want to display non-ASCII characters, you must set `LC_CTYPE`, usually to something like `en_US.UTF-8`.
- You are using Screen, the terminal type (`$TERM`) is declared to be `rxvt-256color`.

There's probably something wrong in your `.zshrc` regarding `TERM`. For `LC_CTYPE`, if you always work in a UTF-8 locale, it's easiest to set it in your `.profile`.

Comment: Regarding screen: Yes, I have it set in my .zlogin to run screen -xRR, so I was running inside screen. Removing this, and setting LC_CTYPE isn't affecting it though.

Comment: @Ali: Did you set `LC_CTYPE` to a valid locale (run `locale -a` to see a list of valid locales)? Try `rxvt-unicode -e zsh -f`. Also, do you have a terminfo entry for `rxvt-256color`? Try with `TERM=rxvt` or `TERM=xterm`, does it make a difference?

Comment: Put some more info in the OP. When running `urxvt-e zsh -f`, and then running mc it does work, and draws the correct lines instead, suggesting it is an issue with zsh. Added .zshrc above too.

Comment: @Ali: **1.** I made a mistake in my answer (will fix): you've set `LANG`, and that's equivalent to setting `LC_CTYPE` (for the purpose at hand). So that's not the problem. **2.** You're missing several environment variables in your `zsh -f` window, do you normally start a login shell? In which case: 2a. [you shouldn't](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/4628#4628); 2b. show us your `.zprofile` and `.zlogin`.

Comment: @Giles: 2a) How do I know?. All shells launched via Awesome WM, which is launched via .xinitrc from slim. 2b) .zprofile and .zlogin are non-existant.

Comment: @Ali: You mentioned a `.zlogin` earlier. Or do you mean you've now removed it for testing? I think you'll need to describe your setup more precisely to resolve this. Since you use `.xinitrc`, you log in on a text console and run `startx`, right? What OS/distribution/release are you using? How do you start your terminals in Awesome? Does starting one by calling `rxvt-unicode` inside another make a difference? What exactly do you call the “parent” and “root” shells?

Comment: Correct, removed `.zlogin` to help diagnose. Boot process: systemd -> slim: login_cmd `exec /bin/sh - ~/.xinitrc %session` -> .xinitrc contains `awesome&` (the WM) -> awesome can run `awful.util.spawn("urxvt")` (which just calls an exec). This shell I have called a 'parent' above. A 'child' is a shell I launch from this 'parent' by calling `urxvt`. OS: Exherbo. When I start one inside another (see 'child', the problem goes away!)

Comment: You were sort of correct, I traced the problem to a collection of conflicting shells used between slim (`sh`), xinitrc (`zsh`) and urxvt (`zsh -l`), and awesome (`sh -e zsh`). Anyway, it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue.
Changed the encoding of my putty session to match the encoding used in terminal.
Thus, changed the putty configuration -> translation to UTF-8

locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=