# How to make exported shell variables permanent?

Tags: linux, shell

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtsocks.so
```

It's ok that I can export in this way, but how can I make it permanent? I want LD_PRELOAD to still be changed after a reboot. I'm using Ubuntu and Fedora

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ordinarily, you'd put your "export" line into whatever shell startup file is appropriate: `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.zprofile`, whatever, in your `$HOME` directory.

If you want to make it permanent for every user, the various shells usually have system-wide config files in `/etc/`: `/etc/profile` exists on this linux box, but do read the man page to figure out which user-specific and which system-wide file to put it in.

Comment: `~/.profile` is the right one for a per-user setting; see [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3052), [Correctly setting environment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4621), and the Super User questions linked in my answer there.

Answer (score 4):

Most distributions also have an `/etc/profile.d/` directory containing a group of .sh and .csh files. Creating a new file in this directory tends to keep items better organized and keeps `/etc/profile` from getting cluttered.