# Unix (Ubuntu Server): $PYTHONPATH resets to blank when I reboot

Tags: ubuntu, python, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make exported shell variables permanent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/how-to-make-exported-shell-variables-permanent)

Each time I set the `$PYTHONPATH` on my new Ubuntu server machine (old Thinkpad) and reboot, it's reset to blank.

I'm setting it like this:

`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7`

If I ask it after that to `echo $PYTHONPATH` it will. And it finds modules on the path. But it loses it when I reboot. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the export command to your `~/.profile` file.  It will get executed every time you login.  To set the value on a system wide basis, you can add it to /etc/environment.

Assuming you are using python 2.7, /usr/lib/python2.7 should be built-in.  You shouldn't need to define PYTHONPATH to access modules located there. To see if it is already included try this before you set PYTHONPATH.  Run python and enter these commands:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `~/.profile` is session-wide, not system-wide. It's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, the information I needed was `etc/environment`. Still learning Unix. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add the assignment to `/etc/environment`, that's what this file is designed for.