# What is the difference between `terminator -e ranger` and ranger from terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, environment-variables, editors

EDIT: I just noticed that when I hit `Enter` on the `ranger` (if it is executed with `terminator -e ranger`) then nano opens while with `e` it uses my main editor. In contrast, when I use a normal shell to execute `ranger` and then I hit `Enter`, my main editor shows up. By normal, I mean if I launch firstly the `terminator` and then the `ranger`.

Why is it different?

Comment: GNOME? I'm not GNOME user but isn't there possible to define somewhere in GNOME session variables? I'm putting some variable in my $HOME/.xinitrc ...

Comment: I use awesome as window manager.

Comment: So what about $HOME/.xsession ?

Comment: How are you launching them?  From the same terminal?  From different terminals?  From the menu?

Comment: The equivalent of pressing Alt+F2 in Gnome/KDE. You could say from the launcher.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Does your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` include a line that sources `.bashrc`?  (e.g. `. ~/.bashrc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your previous question , if you want some environment variable to be set before executing any programs , edit `/etc/profile` (provided you're using bash) , add everything you need. e.g `export EDITOR=nano`

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what is the problem, that is why I changed the question. Nevertheless, I have already in the `~/.bashrc` file that `EDITOR=subl`. Should I export it?

Comment: @DimitrisLeventeas yes , and you really should put this line in /etc/profile , if you insist to put this in ~/.bashrc , make sure it's the first line , depends on your bashrc , it might not be executed

Comment: `/etc/profile` is for all users.  `~/.bashrc` is the right location to change settings for a single user.

Comment: @DimitrisLeventeas Remove the environment variable setting from `.bashrc`, put it in `~/.profile`.

Comment: @warl0ck Why `/etc/profile`? Everything that reads it also reads `~/.profile`. In `.bashrc`, it wouldn't make any difference whether it's the first line or not.

Comment: @Mikel No, `~/.bashrc` is not the analog of `/etc/profile`. `/etc/profile` corresponds to `~/.profile`, they are the place to define environment variables for all users and for yourself respectively. `~/.bashrc` is for shell customizations.

Comment: It's a matter of taste and convention.  I put things that should only happen once per login in `~/.profile`, and once per shell in `~/.bashrc`, but this issue is too complicated to deal with in a comment.  I only wanted to point out that `/etc/profile` would affect all users.

Comment: @Gilles perhaps you're strictly right, but the convention (and the default on Debian, Red Hat, etc.) is that `.bash_profile` sources `.bashrc`, thus setting environment variables in `.bashrc` is more flexible.  For example, it allows you to set new values every time you start a new shell, which could be useful when starting a different terminal emulator, invoking `su`, etc.

Comment: @Mikel `.bash_profile` needs to source `.bashrc` in interactive shells, because bash doesn't read `.bashrc` in login shells. Setting environment variables in `.bashrc` is potentially destructive: sometimes you've purposefully set other values (say, a different `PATH`) in your environment. Not setting your environment variables in your `.profile` causes, among other things, the problem that triggered this question.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I'm aware of that.  But if `.profile` sources `.bashrc` unconditionally, how can it cause this problem?  (I notice in another answer you use `case "$-" in *i*) . ~/.bashrc`, which might be leading to our disagreement.)

Comment: @Mikel Sourcing `.bashrc` from `.profile` is a different matter. Comments aren't the place to discuss this, though. If you want to discuss this further, please come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Answer (score 1):

When you run `terminator -e ranger`, the terminal emulator starts the program `ranger` directly inside it. When you run `terminator` and then start `ranger` in the shell, the terminal emulator runs a shell which runs `ranger`. The main difference is that your shell's interactive initialization file is sourced (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash, `~/.zshrc` for zsh). If your shell rc file sets some environment variables, you'll get different results depending on whether a program was started through an interactive shell or not. Here, it looks like you're setting `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` in your `.bashrc`. If you don't, you get your system's default, which is nano.

The fix is to set environments variable where they should be set, i.e., in your session initialization file. On most setups, this is `~/.profile`. Do not set environment variables in `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or the like. See
[Which setup files should be used for setting up environment variables with bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash/183956)
[Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980)
[Correctly setting environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/correctly-setting-environment/4628)

Comment: Why not?  `.bashrc`, etc are equally valid IMHO.  That's how I do it anyway.  If you run with the defaults of many terminal emulators, `.bash_profile`, etc are only for things you do once per login session, e.g. start `ssh-agent`, run `ssh-add`.  My point is not to claim I know the One True Way, but to observe that blanket statements saying use `.profile` don't acknowledge that the alternative is also fine.

Comment: @Mikel Please read the threads I link to in my answer. Setting environment variables is one of those once-per-session things, done in `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile` or `.login`). Saying that `.bashrc` is equally valid doesn't acknowledge the numerous problems that it causes, one of which was the very source of this question.

Comment: Oh, I see the point you're making.  *If* your distribution's graphical login session ignores `.profile` and `.bashrc`, then putting environment variables in `.bashrc` can make a mismatched environment more likely.  I'm coming from a different angle: I assume the graphical login session sources `.profile` (roughly speaking), and that `.profile` sources `.bashrc` (or similar).  Neither of us has actually established that our assumptions hold in this case AFAICT.